# Request Respone Model / Sync/Async /Event Driven

Tags: spring, rest, architecture

I have requirement i will have to act as middleware system , upstream system makes call to him and i will make a call to third party system with some extra addons . Once i submit request to third party system they give me an id as reponse . I will have to use this id to make another call to get the status of my request , once the status of my request state changes to say done , i will have to invoke one more service to get the details of my request.Once i get response only then i will have to add some extra info to it and send the details back to upstream system.

For this scenario which model will be better 
 Request/ Response ( Synchronous)
  Asynchronous call
  Event driven machanism

The flow between my system and third party system is fixed that part cannot be changed.
Upstream system is going to invoke my service through ESB.
I am planning to use RestFul please let me know your inpusts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use same scheme for your middleware system as using third party system:

> Once i submit request to third party system they give me an id as
>   reponse . I will have to use this id to make another call to get the
>   status of my request , once the status of my request state changes to
>   say done

- So your middleware should return Middleware RequestId on each Upstream request.
- Upstream can check request status for this Middleware RequestId
- When request status changes to `done` upstream can get response.

I create this sequence diagram to demonstrate this simple interaction of `Upstream`, `MiddleWare` and `Thirdparty` systems:

[image]

Comment: which model should i follow rquest /response or async calls

Comment: You should use both:) `upstream` will send request to your `middleware` but `middleware` can't synchronously process this request (due to `thirdparty` system behaviour), so it will return request id to `upstream` and `upstream` later can ask your `middleware` about request status and when its done get proper response. It's async request/response model